# Проверка пользователя в БД(АВТОРИЗАЦИЯ)

Tags: php, sql, yii2

Как правильно сформулировать запрос на существование пользователя в таблице?

```
 $query=User::find();    
$rows = $query
    ->where(['username = :name','password_hash=:pass'])->addParams([':name' => $name, ':pass' => $pass])
    ->limit(10);

    return $rows;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего поле username должно быть уникальным, следовательно получать необходимо одну модель из БД.

```
$user = User:findOne(['username = :name, 'password_hash = :pass'])
    ->addParams([':name' => $name, ':pass' => $pass])->limit(1);
```

В таком случае переменной $user будет присвоена модель, если такая есть в БД, в вашем случае в переменной $rows будет массив моделей, даже, если найдена только одна модель.